# How to read/write an object that has linked lists in a file

Tags: java, oop, class, object, linked-list

I have these classes: "MyClass1", "MyClass2", "MyClass3" and "MyMainClass",

```
public class MyMainClass implements Serializable {
     private String att1, att2, att3;
     private int att4, att5, att6;
     private LinkedList <MyClass1> myClass1List = new LinkedList<MyClass1>();
     private LinkedList <MyClass2> myClass2List = new LinkedList<MyClass2>();
     private LinkedList <MyClass3> myClass3List = new LinkedList<MyClass3>();
}
```

My program create registers (Objects) of "MyMainClass" and deposit it in a LinkedList. I want to save the LinkedList of the objects in a file to get them after i reopen my program. What's the way to do it? I have tried with ObjectOutputStream, but doesn't work. Thanks.

Edit: 
My code to add an object(I just read an example and tried):

```
public static void addObject (MyMainClass p) {
    try {
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile.dat"));
        outputStream.writeObject(p);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: "MyClass1", "MyClass2", "MyClass3" are Serializable.

Comment: What does the code that saves the data, look like? What about the code that reads it?

Comment: Updated with the code.

Comment: When does it error out? During writing or reading?

Comment: There is no error, just myfile.dat hasn't changed.

Comment: So nothing gets written out to the file at all?

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to serialize `myMainClass`, but it doesn't implement `Serializable`. How are you not getting an exception? Another thing: please stick to Java naming conventions. Class names should always start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

I used following for my highschool project long time ago. Due to my poor English skills I do not really understand what class you wish to save and load (LinkedList or myMainClass), but I used this solution to successfully store and load any of my custom objects. I hope you find it handy.

Usage:

```
myMainClass object;
//
// ... your code fillin up the content of object
//
MyIO io = new MyIO();
io.save("", "myfile.dat", object); // "" as first argument will make java use current working directory

// to load the object:

myMainObject object = (myMainObject) io.load("", "myfile.dat");
```

Source:

```
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyIO {

    // String path - path to the directory where the file is supposed to be saved.
    // String filename - the name of the file
    // Object data - object that you wish to save in the file. In your case "myMainClass"

    public void save(String path, String filename, Object data) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + filename, false);
            GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(gzos);
            out.writeObject(data);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    // String path - path to the directory where the file is stored
    // String filename - the name of the file
    // The function returns java object which can be cast to myMainClass.

    public Object load(String path, String filename) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path + filename);
            GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(gzis);
            Object data = in.readObject();
            in.close();
            return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? At least provide some feedback, so I can improve my answers for the future...

Comment: @user1581900 I didn't downvote. But I'd say the problem is that you wrote a bunch of code without any sort of explanation. Also the code is hard to read because it's poorly formatted.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I suppose you are somehow right. I added some comments and explanation, which hopefully boosts the quality of my post. I will keep your critic in mind for the future.

Comment: @user1581900 Good effort, but unfortunately this doesn't address the OP's question. OP is trying to ascertain where he is going wrong.

Comment: @LeonardoLima put your LinkedList as a 3rd argument in save function i.e: io.save("", "myfile.dat", new LinkedList())

Answer (score 1):

I would make "myClass1", "myClass2", and "myClass3" [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), then wrap `myClass1List`, `myClass2List`, and `myClass3List` (and any other data you want to save) in another serializable class so you can use serialization/deserialization to save and restore all of the program state at once.

Unless `myMainClass` is that wrapper, in which case you need to declare that they all implement Serializable.

Comment: I do that, and "myfile.dat" file hasn't changed.

Comment: @LeonardoLima Add `ex.printStackTrace();` to your catch blocks (before exiting) so you can see if any exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: @LeonardoLima You have to print the stack traces before you exit.

Comment: I did it, and nothing changed. :(

Comment: @LeonardoLima You have `System.exit(1);` before `ex.printStackTrace();`.  It needs to be the other way around.

Comment: Thanks, i changed that and nothing are written in "myfile.dat" again.

Answer (score 1):

`myMainClass` isn't marked [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Also, are `myClass1`, `myClass2`, and `myClass3` serializable as well? If not, they should be.

On another note, please follow Java naming conventions; class name should start with an uppercase letter.

**UPDATE**

Are you sure that it's not writing to the file, or is it that the code is throwing exceptions that you cannot see?

In all your `catch` blocks, you have `System.exit(1)`, which gives you absolutely no information about any exceptions that are happening; you're essentially swallowing them. You should at least print out the stacktrace (`ex.printStackTrace()`) so you can see what is going wrong.

Comment: I marked them Serializable, and keeps going wrong, I'll update the code. "myMainClass" actually "Pilot".

Comment: "myfile.dat" just hasn't changed again.

Comment: @LeonardoLima You're swallowing your exceptions. You should print out the stacktrace so you can see what's going on.

Comment: I added "ex.printStackTrace();" and no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: @LeonardoLima Where did you add that statement? If you added it *after* `System.exit(1)`, it will not run. It needs to go before that line.

Comment: @LeonardoLima Do your linked lists contain anything? Or are they empty?